# My Local Fileshare ClickOnce Update Is Not Working, Help?

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a C# application that I'm trying to get to update automatically via ClickOnce.  After publishing newer versions of software, I see the new versions in my publish folder, but when I open the application, it checks for updates, and does nothing (even though there are new files in the publish folder).

What do I need in place for updates to be made automatically?

Edit

What version of Visual Studio are you using?
Visual Studio 2008

Are you deploying the upgrades to the same location as the old version?
They are being published to the same location (not sure about deployed)

Is the installation URL the same? Have you incremented the version number?
Yes

In the Updates dialog reached by clicking the Updates button in the Publish page, do you have "The application should check for updates" checked?
Yes

Do you have "Before the application starts" selected?
Yes

How are you deploying the files?
Not sure

Are you copying them over to the file share or publishing the directly?
Publishing directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where it gets a bit trial and error, since it seems like you're correctly configured. So it must be something to do with your environment.

Is the publish URL different from that which you initially installed it?

This is particularly pertinent if you're talking about this behaviour on your local dev machine whereby you probably first ran from a different location. Such that it'll keep looking for updates in the initial activation path. Suggest trying a full uninstall/reinstall and see if it persists... You could test by looking at `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri`.

If worst comes to absolute worst, then maybe [manually check and run updates](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2007/11/05/manual-check-for-updates-with-clickonce.aspx)?

Useful links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e.aspx
- http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2007/11/05/manual-check-for-updates-with-clickonce.aspx

Answer (score 2):

What version of Visual Studio are you using?
Are you deploying the upgrades to the same location as the old version?
Is the installation URL the same? Have you incremented the version number?
In the Updates dialog reached by clicking the Updates button in the Publish page, do you have "The application should check for updates" checked?
Do you have "Before the application starts" selected?
How are you deploying the files?
Are you copying them over to the file share or publishing the directly?
If you are copying them over there, are you also copying the deployment manifest (whatever.application) for that version to the top of the deployment folder structure?
This is the file that indicates which version should be installed. If you are using VS2008/2010, there is a copy of each version's deployment manifest in each versioned folder (yourapp_a_b_c_d) that you can copy to the root if you are deploying manually.

Comment: I answered these questions in the OP. 
I've been screwing around with my app, and it seems like if I press the APP.application in the publish folder, it updates perfectly, but when I access the application via startmenu shortcut, it doesn't update...

Comment: What are the publishing file location URL and the installation URL? And did you fill in the URL on the Updates screen, and if so, what is the value of that?

Comment: Running the deployment manifest (yourapp.application) is basically what an update does, so it's good that that works. It helps narrow down the problem. Seems like there's something out of whack.